# Ubuntu: Environment variables set in .bashrc but not being used in cron?

Tags: ubuntu, environment-variables, cron

I have set some `environ` varibales in `.bashrc` but they end up as `None` when the script is run by `cron`. When I run it using `python3` it works perfectly.

Set the variables:

```
nano .bashrc
```

`.bashrc`

```
export NBB="Hello"
```

When I do in shell:
python3

```
os.environ.get('NBB')
```

prints Hello

In cron running the same script:

```
os.environ.get('NBB')
```

output: None

Am I supposed to set the variable somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

.bashrc is *your* profile and cron *probably isn't running as you* unless you set it up to.

When you launch Python, it IS running as you.

I *think* cron runs as root by default... (edit correction) cron usually runs as the cron user but the reasoning is the same.

Try setting you variables in `/etc/environment` as ***these will be system wide***.  If this creates a security problem, search for setting environment variables as root.

Answer (score 0):

As in bash documentation

```
Execute commands from file instead of the standard personal initialization file ~/.bashrc if the shell is interactive
```

the key part:  **~/.bashrc if the shell is interactive**

Even if you run cron as your user (and not cron user as in most common examples), cron is not interactive.

Answer (score 0):

lets say your cronjob currently lives at

```
/full/path/to/my/original/process/launched/by/cron
```

lets create a new file /full/path/to/this/defineVars and populate it with lines like

```
export foo=bar                      #  give this your actual env var definition
export yetAnotherVar=someCoolValue  #  ditto
```

save this file make certain there are NO spaces around the = sign and put single quotes around the value of the environment variable if the value contains spaces or such

now create a new wrapper file called /full/path/my/wrapperToCronjob

vi  /full/path/my/wrapperToCronjob   # edit this file and give it below content

```
source /full/path/to/this/defineVars  #  jack up local environment with vars

/full/path/to/my/original/process/launched/by/cron
```

now make the new wrapper executable by issuing

```
chmod +x /full/path/my/wrapperToCronjob
```

update your cronjob to execute file  /full/path/my/wrapperToCronjob    instead of /full/path/to/my/original/process/launched/by/cron

Essentially what above does is create a file containing all your env var definitions  ... then source this file from inside a wrapper bash script which then executes your original process which cron originally launched directly ... then update the cronjob to execute this wrapper script instead of your original process

This design pattern is very common and it separates out your env var definitions into its own file and allows you to do other preliminary tasks inside the wrapper script as well as other post processing steps after processing finishes also from the wrapper script

Critically this also clearly defines all the necessary env vars needed by your processes and allows the cronjob to be run by your prod user instead of root or your own user

Answer (score 0):

Because I wanted to use dynamic environment variables, a lot of solutions didn't work for me. When using Debian's vixie-cron (and Ubuntu's) for my bash script, I found the best way was to use the the existing environment for the user's crontab:

```
*/5 * * * * "BASH_ENV=$HOME/.profile $HOME/my_bash_script.sh"
```